# Oracle XE 11g (ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor )

Tags: java, oracle

I have already seen the questioned in the stack overflow that might relate to my problem but let me emphasize that none of them could resolve my issue.

issue is: when I wanted to integrate OWASP WebGoat application with oracle XE 11g , I receive the above mentioned error.

connection URL in web.xml is:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE/${USER}
```

=================================================================
listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER = 
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Amir-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

=============================================================
tnsnames.ora:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Amir-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )



EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

===================================================================
java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

===================================================================
output of the lsnrctl services:

```
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 09-MAY-2014 16:34
:07

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: AMIR-PC, pid: 5740>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Amir-PC)(PORT=2403))
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

=====================================================================
output of the tnsping xe :

```
TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 09-MAY-2
014 16:35:19

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Amir-PC)
(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (0 msec)
```

could some one please help me resolve this issue? I have been struggling more than 3 days and not found any useful answer yet.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64600/discussion-on-question-by-amir-avarzamani-oracle-xe-11g-ora-12514-tnslistener).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you said your `web.xml` contains:

```
<init-param>
 <param-name>DatabaseConnectionString</param-name>
 <!-- The string "${USER}" in the connection string will be replaced
      by the active username when making a connection. -->
 <param-value>
  <!--jdbc:hsqldb:mem:${USER}-->
  <!--jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe/${USER}-->
  jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521
 </param-value>
</init-param>
```

The connection string you showed at the top of the question is commented out, so you're actually connecting with `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521`. That isn't supplying a service name; but your `listener.ora` does have `DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)`, [so this *should* be the equivalent of](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/network.11203/e10835/listener.htm#BGBJJBCF) `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE`. (I've tested this with 11gR2 EE and the parentheses around the `XE` in the `listener.ora` don't seem to matter).

But that doesn't quite seem to work as expected. When you changed that and set the user name explicitly:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@//localhost:1521/XE
```

... the TNS-12514 went away and was replaced with an ORA-01017, invalid username/password. That means the connection string is now working and your `system` account's password is something other than `system`. With a valid username and password it looks like it should now work.

If the `${USER}` substitution works as the comment in the `web.xml` suggests, and contains both the username and password, then making your connection string look like this ought to work:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:${USER}@//localhost:1521/XE
```

But only if `${USER}` is actually a valid `username/password` string.

Comment: you are right but my problem is persisted and not gone. i am sure my user/pass is valid because i can login to Oracle web interface successfully.

Comment: @AmirAvarzamani - your TNS-12514 error is gone. Are `Amir-PC` and `localhost` the same machine - all of this is on your own box, and `Amir-PC` resolves to `127.0.0.1`? Otherwise you might be looking at two databases, which would explain a lot, but seems unlikely you'd have missed that.

Comment: And based on the other question you asked on DBA, does using `amir/amir` also get an ORA-01017?

Comment: I  changed Amir-PC to localhost and 127.0.0.1 and without any effect. yes I am working on a single machine.

Comment: yes Alex.its wierd but amir/amir is also giving me logon error. :(

Comment: Passwords are case sensitive, but it looks like you're using the same case as when you created the user. Have you granted connect privs to the new user? That would get a different error though. Not quite sure what's going on now... you can connect as `amir/amir` through SQL*Plus, or other clients? Maybe the app you're using is overriding the credentials somehow, but not familiar with it.

Comment: Yes Alex. I can login using web interface and using sqlplus system/system@XE but using amir/amir@XE it gives me: ORA-01045: user AMIR lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied

Comment: how to grant all to asystem or amir on XE?

Comment: Do not grant anything to `system`, it has everything it needs - don't mess with built-in accounts or objects. For the other one you need at least `grant create session to amir`, which should let you log in to SQL*Plus. But I don't think that will resolve the ORA-01017 through WebGoat.

Comment: I have asked this question from the subscribed mailing list in the OWASP WebGoat as well but no respond from them. also I dont think there should be some where in the java code to hardcode the username and password of the DB because AFAIK that should be placed inside the web.xml in connection string.

Comment: @AmirAvarzamani - I agree, I just don't understand what you're seeing, if `amir/amir` is getting ORA-01017. Just a thought.

Comment: either using this ==> jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@//localhost:1521/XE or this ==> jdbc:oracle:thin:amir/amir@//localhost:1521/XE  ORA-01017 will be raised.